# Dropdownlist generator resetting options after submit

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Im working on some code that requires lots of dropdown lists and I decided to make an function that generates dropdown lists to cut down the amount of code used for the dropdown lists.

But the problem im getting is that the values of the dropdown lists reset after every 'submit'..

```
function generateDrop($name, $optionsValue, $optionDesc, $header)
{
    echo' 
        <p>'.$header.' 
        <select name="'.$name.'" type="text" >
            <option value="" disabled>Choose here</option>
            ';
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($optionsValue); $i++)
    {
        echo'<option value ="'.$optionsValue[$i].'">';
        if(isset($optionDesc[$i]))
        {
            echo $optionDesc[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            echo $optionsValue[$i];
        }
        echo '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select> </p>';
}
```

Comment: You mean it's resetting to the default "Choose here" after a submit? This is to be expected, because the page re-loads. If you want to have it "remember" your choice, you'll need to do something like pass the selected option into this function (from the `$_POST` data, or a session, whatever might make sense based on the rest of your code), and add something here to include the "selected" attribute on the one that matches the value you pass in.

Comment: Thanks, its working now, with echo "selected" !